# Why won't this simple javascript function do what it is supposed to?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to write a function that will make a string of random numbers appear one after the other inside an html

element. See the function below:

```
document.getElementById("button-1").onclick = function () {
  var numbersArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var newNumbersArray = [];

  function createNewArray (array) {
    for (i=0;i<50;i++) {
      array.push(numbersArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]);
    }
    return array;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < newNumbersArray.length; j++) {
    document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = newNumbersArray[j];
  }
}
```

The first part of the function takes an array of numbers 0-10 and creates a new array 50 elements long made up of random numbers from the variable numbersArray.  Then the function is *supposed* to display each number one after the other on the html page (note that I am aware this would happen so fast that you would only see the last number. I plan to later add a timer, right now I am just trying to get the basic functionality). However, when I click the button the html page, absolutely nothing happens. What am I missing?

Many thanks for your help. I am a newbie (probably quite obvious).

Comment: Nothing showed on the page because `newNumbersArray` is empty. You have an indexOutOfException.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never called `createNewArray`

```js
document.getElementById("button-1").onclick = function () {
  var numbersArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  var newNumbersArray;

  function createNewArray (array) {
    for (i=0;i<50;i++) {
      array.push(numbersArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]);
    }
    return array;
  }
  
  // this is required
  newNumbersArray = createNewArray([]);

  for (j = 0; j < newNumbersArray.length; j++) {
    document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = newNumbersArray[j];
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='number-display'></div>
<button id="button-1">Action</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `createNewArray()`, maybe you're missing:

```
newNumbersArray = createNewArray(numbersArray)
```

Also, this looks weird because you're overwritting the value multiple times:

```
for (j = 0; j < newNumbersArray.length; j++) {
  document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = newNumbersArray[j];
}
```

You could do:

```
document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = '';
for (j = 0; j < newNumbersArray.length; j++) {
  document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML += newNumbersArray[j] + ",";
}
```

But there is an easier way:

```
document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = newNumbersArray[j].join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I found in your code is that you are defining a **function** called `createNewArray` but you never use it.

The solution should be:

```
createNewArray(newNumbersArray)
```

However, I'd recommend you to do the following:

```js
document.getElementById("button-1").onclick = function () {
  var newNumbersArray;

  function createNewArray () {
    // instead of passing a parameter which will be modified, 
    // you can create a variable inside your function and return it
    var array = [];
    for (i=0;i<50;i++) {
      // array.push(numbersArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*11)])
      // the line above is practically the same as the line bellow
      array.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
    }
    return array;
  }
  
  // so you can use it in this way
  newNumbersArray = createNewArray();

  for (j = 0; j < newNumbersArray.length; j++) {
    document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = newNumbersArray[j];
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="number-display"></div>
<button id="button-1">Action</button>
```